RAID0 Superblock Lost, but Data (Assumed) Intact; How to Recover?
My computer's Intel RST RAID0 has always been a bit unreliable and would often have trouble booting (first two attempts would fail, third one would succeed), but recently I accidentally touched the VMD setting in UEFI and when I switched it back, one of the SSDs got dropped from the array. And yes, I have backups of essential information, but I also have a lot of stuff in my Downloads folder that I don't want to have to go to the trouble of downloading again. I think the data is probably still intact on the drive, and I just need to force Intel RST to recognize the old drive as part of the array.
I've done a bit of preliminary research and attempted a few things, but to start with something here's the output of lsblk and mdadm -E for each drive, as well as mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -o name,size,fstype,type,mountpoint
NAME          SIZE FSTYPE          TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         1.6G squashfs        loop /rofs
loop1         471M squashfs        loop 
loop2       874.4M squashfs        loop 
loop3           4K squashfs        loop /snap/bare/5
loop4        74.3M squashfs        loop /snap/core22/1564
loop5       269.8M squashfs        loop /snap/firefox/4793
loop6       149.6M squashfs        loop /snap/thunderbird/507
loop7       116.8M squashfs        loop /snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237
loop8        10.7M squashfs        loop /snap/firmware-updater/127
loop9       505.1M squashfs        loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
loop10       10.5M squashfs        loop /snap/snap-store/1173
loop11       91.7M squashfs        loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop12        500K squashfs        loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/178
loop13       38.8M squashfs        loop /snap/snapd/21759
sda          14.6G iso9660         disk 
├─sda1        5.8G iso9660         part /cdrom
├─sda2          5M vfat            part 
├─sda3        300K                 part 
└─sda4        8.8G ext4            part /var/crash
sdb          29.8G                 disk 
└─sdb1       29.8G vfat            part /media/ubuntu/LINUX_SOFT
nvme1n1       1.9T isw_raid_member disk 
nvme2n1       1.9T                 disk 
├─nvme2n1p1   100M                 part 
├─nvme2n1p2    16M                 part 
├─nvme2n1p3   1.9T                 part 
└─nvme2n1p4   604M                 part 
nvme0n1       1.9T isw_raid_member disk 

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/nvme0n1
/dev/nvme0n1:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.3.00
    Orig Family : b6efc272
         Family : b6efc272
     Generation : 00000b7f
  Creation Time : Unknown
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : bd57bb23:b7610b20:5e73fbd0:b7cafca4
       Checksum : c5a258a9 correct
    MPB Sectors : 2
          Disks : 3
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk01 Serial : 2L2529Q5D2UD
          State : active
             Id : 00000001
    Usable Size : 4000792576 (1907.73 GiB 2048.41 GB)

[OS]:
       Subarray : 0
           UUID : b723ce70:4b1ad650:fcf8fea6:d0e35caf
     RAID Level : 0
        Members : 3
          Slots : [U__]
    Failed disk : 1
      This Slot : 1 (out-of-sync)
    Sector Size : 512
     Array Size : 12002377728 (5.59 TiB 6.15 TB)
   Per Dev Size : 4000792840 (1907.73 GiB 2048.41 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 125024768
     Chunk Size : 16 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : failed
    Dirty State : clean
     RWH Policy : off
      Volume ID : 1

  Disk00 Serial : 2L252LQ558FE
          State : active
             Id : 00000000
    Usable Size : 4000792576 (1907.73 GiB 2048.41 GB)

  Disk02 Serial : 2L252LQGQ7UY:0
          State : active
             Id : ffffffff
    Usable Size : 4000792576 (1907.73 GiB 2048.41 GB)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/nvme1n1
/dev/nvme1n1:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.3.00
    Orig Family : b6efc272
         Family : b6efc272
     Generation : 00000b7f
  Creation Time : Unknown
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : bd57bb23:b7610b20:5e73fbd0:b7cafca4
       Checksum : c5a258a9 correct
    MPB Sectors : 2
          Disks : 3
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk00 Serial : 2L252LQ558FE
          State : active
             Id : 00000000
    Usable Size : 4000792576 (1907.73 GiB 2048.41 GB)

[OS]:
       Subarray : 0
           UUID : b723ce70:4b1ad650:fcf8fea6:d0e35caf
     RAID Level : 0
        Members : 3
          Slots : [U__]
    Failed disk : 1
      This Slot : 0
    Sector Size : 512
     Array Size : 12002377728 (5.59 TiB 6.15 TB)
   Per Dev Size : 4000792840 (1907.73 GiB 2048.41 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 125024768
     Chunk Size : 16 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : failed
    Dirty State : clean
     RWH Policy : off
      Volume ID : 1

  Disk01 Serial : 2L2529Q5D2UD
          State : active
             Id : 00000001
    Usable Size : 4000792576 (1907.73 GiB 2048.41 GB)

  Disk02 Serial : 2L252LQGQ7UY:0
          State : active
             Id : ffffffff
    Usable Size : 4000792576 (1907.73 GiB 2048.41 GB)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/nvme2n1
/dev/nvme2n1:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop11
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop13
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop10
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop12
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop9
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop8
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda4
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda3
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/nvme2n1p4
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/nvme2n1p3
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/nvme2n1p2
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/nvme2n1p1
mdadm: no IMSM anchor on /dev/nvme2n1
mdadm: Failed to load all information sections on /dev/nvme2n1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/nvme2n1
mdadm: /dev/loop7 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop7
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop7
mdadm: /dev/loop6 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop6
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop6
mdadm: /dev/loop5 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop5
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop5
mdadm: /dev/loop4 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop4
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop4
mdadm: /dev/loop3 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop3
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop3
mdadm: /dev/loop2 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop2
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop2
mdadm: /dev/loop1 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop1
mdadm: /dev/loop0 is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: No OROM/EFI properties for /dev/loop0
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop0
mdadm: /dev/nvme0n1 is identified as a member of /dev/md/imsm0, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/nvme1n1 is identified as a member of /dev/md/imsm0, slot 0.
mdadm: added /dev/nvme0n1 to /dev/md/imsm0 as 1
mdadm: added /dev/nvme1n1 to /dev/md/imsm0 as 0
mdadm: Container /dev/md/imsm0 has been assembled with 2 drives
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop11
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop13
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop10
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop12
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop9
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop8
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda4
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda3
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/nvme0n1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/nvme2n1p4
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/nvme2n1p3
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/nvme2n1p2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/nvme2n1p1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/nvme2n1
mdadm: /dev/nvme1n1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop7
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop6
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop5
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop4
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop3
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop1
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop0
mdadm: looking in container /dev/md/imsm0
mdadm: found match on member /md127/0 in /dev/md/imsm0
mdadm: /dev/md/OS_0 has been assembled with 2 devices but cannot be started.
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: /dev/nvme0n1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/nvme1n1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: looking in container /dev/md/imsm0
mdadm: member /md127/0 in /dev/md/imsm0 is already assembled

If the best we can do is get Ubuntu able to read the drive so I can save everything that wasn't backed up, then so be it, but ideally I'd like to just get the drives working again with Intel RST so I can boot back into Windows or, at least, be able to run chkdsk and repair the existing installation. This is also a Bitlocker drive, but I have the recovery keys saved.
One thing I have read about is just using mdmadm --create, will data in my main partition be overwritten if I use that?
